# php hide a dynamically constructed element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have an ul with some li something like this

```
<?php
   for($i=0; $i<5; i++) { 
      $id_name = "link" . $i;
      echo "<ul><a href='#' id=$id_name >list</a>
               <li class='on'>1</li>
               <li class='on'>2</li>
               <li class='on'>3</li>
            </ul> ";
    }
?>
```

and css :

```
.off{display:none;} .on{display:block;}
```

I want every time I click a link to hide all `li` elements of this link. I tried jQuery with `toggleClass()` function but I can't do nothing is I don't know the id of the link. I read something about `child()` and `parent()` functions. Can I use this way? (sorry for the programming mistakes i am new to php)

Comment: The only valid children of `<ul>` tags are `<li>` tags ... I'd fix the HTML first then work on the JavaScript (as the structure will be different)...

Answer (score 2):

Why not giving a link tag some class name as example `myLink`, like following code :

```
echo "<ul><a href='#' id=$id_name class='myLink'>list</a>
           <li class='on'>1</li>
           <li class='on'>2</li>
           <li class='on'>3</li>
        </ul>
```

And later on in jquery you can target `myLink` class name **and** use [`.siblings()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiIpNbKts7JAhXDTY4KHd45CrgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fsiblings%2F&usg=AFQjCNG8NmUDKe0tz1nxFzvJDTfo_e3suA&bvm=bv.109332125,d.c2E) as `A` tag are siblings of `li` element.Thus no need for `.child()` or `.parent()`. See following code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.myLink', function () {
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass('off');
});
```

One thing to consider, if you defined already `on` class name on `li` element, using `toggleClass('off')` would only add and remove `off` class name but not the `on` class name. To get desire result, use this css :

```
.off {
  display:none !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/90jk1k95/)

*p/s : `A` tag should not be there as it not a valid markup for `UL`*

Comment: Yeah, as worst HTML structured would broken jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().find('li').toggleClass('off');
});
```

or :

```
 $('a').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().children('li').toggleClass('off');
    });
```

or:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
     $(this).nextAll('li').toggleClass('off');
    });
```

Comment: Think you might want `$(this).parent().find() ... ` ? Though, admittedly the HTML is badly structured.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery you can just add a function in your html. No need to have a class for hiding and showing (unless you are applying animations or something to your css classes). As mentioned by another user, you should remove the anchor from your list and place it outside or as a list item itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('li').toggle();
  });
});
```